# How to install basic auth on graphite and grafana

Tags: graphite, basic-authentication, grafana

I've installed Graphite and grafana and all is working correctly.

I need to add basic authentication for graphite and grafana.

How can I do that?

Graphite conf file:
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/graphite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess _graphite processes=5 threads=5 display-name='%{GROUP}' inactivity-timeout=120 user=_graphite group=_graphite
    WSGIProcessGroup _graphite
    WSGIImportScript /usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi process-group=_graphite application-group=%{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi

    Alias /content/ /usr/share/graphite-web/static/
    <Location "/content/">
            SetHandler None
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/graphite-web_error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/graphite-web_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to access your graphite dist in python packlages:

e.g

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/graphite
```

the you should have a file `manage.py`

run:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
```

you might also need to run:

```
graphite-manage syncdb
```